# Sending Format with Rspec GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mobile, rspec, user-agent

I'm attempted to test the mobile version of my rails site, but i can't seem to get the following code to work:

```
let(:uri) { '/' }

it 'routes to #mobile_index' do
  get uri, :format => 'mobile'
  controller.response.should route_to('home#index_mobile')
end
```

What's the proper way to send this sort of request so its seen by the app as coming from a mobile source? I've looked up a lot about setting the user agent, but i can't get any of those to work either. I'm using Rspec version 2.14.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you check if whether to redirect to mobile page or to the normal?

For this testcode to work you must be having something like this in your application#index

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.mobile do
  # redirect to mobile
  end  

  format.html 

 end
```

This means if you call '/index' (or '/' ) and if you call '/index.mobile' it would be
redirecting to the mobile page

Because you've written something about the User Agent i guess this is your criterium for
distinguishing between mobile and normal version.

HTTP Headers in rails tests are set by the `request.env` method. Their names are prefixed 
with `HTTP_`, capitalized and have dashes replaced by underscores.

so for setting the `User-Agent` header you just do

```
   request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = "WWW-Mechanize"
```

and then perform the get call.

If you are checking only one and not multiple controllers in integration i would also make this a functional test of the Application Controller (or whatever controller responsible for the home action)

```
describe ApplicationController do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "redirects mobile agents to the mobile version" do
      request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'Ipod ...'
      #calls "/index" unless different routing configured
      get :index 
      expect(response).to redirect_to <index_mobile_path> #path helper depends on route config
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So this works for testing the redirect Thanks! but i'm trying also to test for visiting a page, i have the following `it "goes to mobile index" do
      controller.request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-us; HTC_DesireS_S510e Build/GRI40) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1"
      visit "/"
      puts page.html` and it won't return me the mobile version

Comment: visit is a capybara method. so requst.env does not work here. this is rack stuff.
Testing the visit to the root page and then the actual rendering of the mobile page involves 2 controller actions and is therefore an integration test. Capybara User Agent is set differently. 
idk if that is driver dependent, but for poltergeist you just do
`page.driver.headers = { "User-Agent" => "Poltergeist" }` see [doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jonleighton/poltergeist/frames)

Comment: It's sure nice to have to integration test this behaviour, but i would omit the extra effort. You checked that the redirect is send correctly, you can check the mobile page in a sepatate test. What should go wrong between? The value this integration test brings to the confidence of having a working software is negligable, imho